# How to commit changes to Git in Angular Schematic

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

I would like my [Angular Schematic](https://v12.angular.io/guide/schematics-for-libraries#schematics-for-libraries) for `ng add` to automatically commit its changes to Git. Adding a `Rule` to commit the changes to Git after all my other `Rule`s doesn't work properly because it executes too early and misses most of the changes:

```ts
export function ngAdd(): Rule {
  return chain([ 
    /* all my rules */
    gitCommit()
  ]);
}

function gitCommit(message: string): Rule {
  return () => {
    execSync(`git add .`).toString();
    execSync(`git commit -m "${message}"`).toString();
  }
}
```

It makes sense that this doesn't work because `Rule`s make changes to the `Tree` and not directly on the file system. Therefore, the `Rule` returned by `gitCommit()` would execute before the changes from the previous `Rule`s are applied to the file system.

## Question

How can I run a task after the transformed `Tree` is applied to the file system within the Schematic?

Comment: Just for clarification you want all the changes done by schematics to be commited in git?

Comment: That is correct. I am looking for the same experience as what you get with `ng new` where the Angular CLI creates an "initial commit" with everything it's created. After `ng new`, the developer can run my `ng add` schematic, with all changes again automatically added to Git in a separate commit.

Comment: Check this, they are doing it using Task not rule. 
https://github.dev/angular/angular-cli/blob/fe746463f93899586dd0273b16cb12b7bde7f484/packages/schematics/angular/ng-new/index.ts#L90